# InCorrect XML formats are not Rejecting while Validating XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am validating  string weathere it has valid XML format? While i have Added incorrect XML format which is

Incorrect formats which need to be rejected are Accepting

```
      string Parameters="ABC>"

      string parameters="ABC"
```

Coorect format which  need to be accepted is Rejected

```
      string parameters=<Paramnumber AAA="120901" />
```

is Rejecting

my code is :

```
public bool IsValidXML(string value)
{
    try
    {
        // Check we actually have a value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
        {
            // Try to load the value into a document
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.LoadXml("<root>" + Parameters+ "</root>");

            // If we managed with no exception then this is valid XML!
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // A blank value is not valid xml
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Xml.XmlException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please let me know  how can i handle these properly.

Regards,
Channa

Comment: Both `<root>ABC></root>` and `<root>ABC</root>` are valid XML documents... it's not clear why you expected them to be rejected. But for your third example, that's not a valid string literal in C#, so it wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct syntax for the 3rd one should be

```
      string parameters = "<Paramnumber AAA=\"120901\" />";
```

But you're looking for something else I guess.